# location.href is not working in server.js NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, npm

In the below code, I am trying to send it to the login page but it is not working.

```
app.get('/current-pass', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "currentPass.html"));
})

app.post('/current-pass', (req, res) => {
let { email, cpassword } = req.body;

if(cpassword.value){
  return res.json({ 'alert': "please enter your current password"});
}

db.collection('users').doc(email).get()
.then(user => {
  bcrypt.compare(cpassword, user.data().password, (err, result) => {
    if(result){
      let data = user.data();
      return res.json({
        location.href = "/login"; // This is not working
      })
    } else{
      return res.json({'alert': 'current password is incorrect'});
    }
  })
})

})
```

All of the code is working but `location.href` is not working.
In the place of,

```
return res.json({
 location.href = "/login";
})
```

I used,

```
return res.send('success');
```

But it is also not working

Comment: You are doing a "form post" to your html. You won't be able to do a redirect like this. The redirect should come from within your html javascript code that is run on the client side based on the result you get from your `post` call, like success:false or failed to authenticate.

Having said all this, this is a really old approach to web application development. You should learn Web 2.0 and Single page application by using something like React or Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `res.redirect('/login');` to redirect with Express.js. There is no `location` variable in a request.

Comment: This error is coming: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

Comment: It's because you're parsing the response as JSON when you don't need to. Just let it redirect.

Comment: Thanks! My problem is solved.